# android:background changed title background color

Tags: android, android-styles

I have different themes in styles.xml and I have used different `background` color in each theme.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimary</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDark</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/transparent</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@android:color/black</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:background">#181818</item>
</style>
<style name="AppThemeLight" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/colorPrimaryLight</item>
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/colorPrimaryDarkLight</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccentLight</item>
    <item name="android:background" >@color/backgroundLight</item>
</style>
```

xml snippet,

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
    <include layout="@layout/content_main" />
    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:elevation="0dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">
        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:background="@android:color/transparent"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

When I change the theme, the `title background` also changed to that color.

I tried using the following in each theme,But it doesn't work.

```
<item name="android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle">@style/titletheme</item>
```

And titletheme ,

```
<style name="titletheme">
    <item name="android:background">#00000000</item>
</style>
```

See the image, the title background is changed with `android:background` color in that theme.

[image]

How to prevent change of the title background color?

Comment: don't set a background color?

Comment: can you explain why? I want to display common background color for whole application But I dont want it for title.

Comment: @JyotiJK can u share your activity theme also with question

Comment: @NileshRathod I have used many themes, I just edited my question with sample styles

Comment: declare a toolbar theme and make it a part of your existing themes, what is happening is Toolbar is picking popupoverlay theme which is not defined in your themes(those written over here), best way to do is..create a toolbar theme, and check

Comment: @Ashwani thanks, let me try

Comment: @Ashwani I tried `<style name="AppTheme.PopupOverlay" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" >
                <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
    </style>` But it doesn't work

Comment: lemme write a quick hack for you

Comment: @JyotiJK just change one thing and tell me its working or not:
remove "android:background" from your theme and add "android:windowBackground". see if this helps.
rest leave the same

Comment: @Ashwani Thanks a lot. It worked :) . Please post it as answer

Comment: Your welcome...happy coding..:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change one thing and tell me its working or not: remove "android:background" from your theme and add "android:windowBackground". see if this helps. rest leave the same.

Comment: worked for me too but now where should I set my background color?

Comment: @Prashant set your background color in android:windowBackground (in style.xml) and in toolbar add android:background, and support the answer if it helped you...